# URL Shortner... Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to build a simple URL shortner and I have come across a few complications:

A) in .htaccess how would I rewrite mydomain.com to make it so users can enter mydomain.com/4854 while the page is actually mydomain.com/url.php?key=4854.

B) If I do have that Rewrite rule how can I be sure to bypass it for index.php and add.php

Thanks so much in advanced.

Comment: What have you tried already (if anything at all), and what is an invalid key? A string? Any non-numeric input?

Comment: @JamWaffles Sorry about the invalid key; I got a little messed up.. I'll remove it. And I am not that good at htaccess and I haven't found anything on Google that helps me with this.

Comment: A) is answered a thousand times on this site already. B) The same, standard. C) Well that's really hard, so I tell you: `include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(/)?$ /url.php?key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rewrites requests that contain only numbers to `url.php`.

Then in `url.php`, if key is not found, redirect to error page.

Comment: thanks @webbiedave, Just out of curiosity what does [QSA,L] mean/do?

Comment: [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa): Appends any query string from the original request URL to any query string created in the rewrite target. [L](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l): Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules.

Comment: @webbiedave: Redirect? Why not just `inlcude` to spare the roundtrip?

Comment: Redirect, include... heck, send them an SMS and follow it up with a postcard. I'm not worried about the small dog here :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(/)?$ url.php?key=$1
```

And if the key is invalid, redirect in the php file

Answer (score 0):

Let me save you the grief...I was doing the same thing, and found it written for me at [yourls.org](http://yourls.org/).  It covers pretty much everything you need, as well as giving you option user pages to add their own, AND gives you an API interface for others to use the shortened URLS.  I had it up and running in minutes, and spent a couple of hours modifying the samples given to be ready for production.

Even if you don't use it, the mod_rewrite solution is there for you.